# How to get the segments a user-id belongs to?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

Does a way exist, where I can get for a specific user-id, the information in witch segments this specific user is?

In the Export Schema https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en is the segment not available. I know that I can build the segments by myself in BigQuery but than I have the issue that this can by slightly different from the UI.

Edit:
The solution is in: [How to get the segments a user-id belongs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503183/how-to-get-the-segments-a-user-id-belongs-to#comment112294949_63504160)

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass it in Google Analytics as custom dimension, then you can find it in the reports, filters or segments.

Comment: What i want is, to have the segment that i *build in GA* in BigQuery or as Information in a API. I Know that i can build segments in Bigquery and pass this information to GA. 
But i have a UI to create a Segement in GA and i want to used it...

Comment: Segments are at the level of the user who creates them, not the Analytics account. It doesn't make sense to say that segments aren't in the BigQuery Export, neither are the filters or Analytics settings there, it's just the data. At this point I believe that there is no response to your request.

Comment: Thx but i can for example https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6015314?hl=en create a audiences from segments and publish it to Google Ads, Display & Video 360, or Optimize. But i can't get this Information outside of the "google universe"?

Comment: You can't, after you create an audience, you can use it in the account you shared it with (i.e. Google Ads account).